# How to do Bitmap processing using BitmapData?

Tags: c#, bitmap, bitmapdata

I've built a small test example where the goal is to change all pixels in my `.png` to white. I'm doing it using `BitmapData`, because as I understand it, the performance is better. If I can get it working; then I can change which pixels I'm changing and add different conditions to altering a pixel color. But I'm stuck on just this simple test.

Here's my C# :

```
public static void TestConvertAllBlackBitmapToAllWhite()
{
    string allBlackPNGFullFilePath = @"C:\Users\{Username}\Desktop\50x50AllBlack.png";
    Bitmap allBlackBitmap = new Bitmap(allBlackPNGFullFilePath);

    Bitmap newBitmap = (Bitmap)allBlackBitmap.Clone();

    Size size = newBitmap.Size;
    PixelFormat pixelFormat = newBitmap.PixelFormat;
    byte bitDepth = (byte)(pixelFormat == PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb ? 4 : 3);
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, size);
    BitmapData bitmapData = newBitmap.LockBits(rectangle, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, pixelFormat);
    int dataSize = bitmapData.Stride * bitmapData.Height;
    byte[] data = new byte[dataSize];
    Marshal.Copy(bitmapData.Scan0, data, 0, dataSize);

    Color white = Color.White;

    for (int y = 0; y < size.Height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < size.Width; x++)
        {
            // Get Index
            int index = y * bitmapData.Stride + x * bitDepth;

            // Set Pixel Color
            data[index] = white.B;
            data[index + 1] = white.G;
            data[index + 2] = white.R;
        }
    }

    Marshal.Copy(data, 0, bitmapData.Scan0, data.Length);
    newBitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);

    // Save New Converted Bitmap
    string originalFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(allBlackPNGFullFilePath);
    string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(allBlackPNGFullFilePath);
    string newBitmapFileName = originalFileName + "_Converted";
    string newBitmapFullFileName = directory + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString() + newBitmapFileName + ".png";

    newBitmap.Save(newBitmapFullFileName, ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

My input is an all black 50x50 `.png` : [image: All Black 50 x 50 PNG]

The problem is the output I'm getting is another all black `.png` instead of an all white one.

How can I fix up my simple example code to produce an all white `.png` as a result?

Any help / guidance will be really appreciated.

Comment: Use Wiki to determine why the bits are black : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

Comment: You are reaing a png file and never set the alpha channel. Try to add `data[index + 3] = white.A;`  !

Comment: @TaW. Tried it, but it still yields another all black `.png`. I checked the pixel format is : 'Format32bppArgb' and the bitDepth is : 3.

Comment: No, this can't be ! - Format32bppArgb' must be bitDepth = 4 !!

Comment: Ah. Sorry, my mistake. The pixel format is : 'Format24bppRgb'. Not 'Format32bppArgb' as I mentioned above.

Comment: Really?  Then the error is to open the data as Readonly. Make it `BitmapData bitmapData = newBitmap.LockBits(rectangle, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, pixelFormat);` and it will work.

Comment: That does the trick :D. Thanks for pointing out the glaring little detail.

Comment: Yup, missed three time myself. For flexible code I would still add something like `if (bitDepth  == 4 ) data[index + 3] = white.A;`

Comment: For changing a bitmap to pure white, I really don't think this is the most efficient way; fairly sure the normal drawing classes have a simple `Fill` to do this. Also, you should dispose your stuff when you're done with it. With the method you're using, the clone is completely unneeded, btw. And you can also just copy the bytes out and then unlock and dispose the original image, and then you can build these bytes into a new image and save it back to the same filename.

Comment: Thanks for the tips @Nyerguds. My code above is an example of an initial test. The only problems I'm experiencing now; is performance. So I'm looking into GPU image processing, but I'm struggling to find clear instructions of how to try something like that.

Comment: @TaW If you post your comment as an answer I'll gladly mark it.

Comment: Sorry but I don't post answers here any longer. You may either self-answer or simply delete it, as it was really not much more than a typo..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Taw

It's a little thing on this line :

```
BitmapData bitmapData = newBitmap.LockBits(rectangle, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, pixelFormat);
```

The `ImageLockMode` is set to `ReadOnly`. Since I'm making changes to the `BitmapData` while looping; the `ImageLockMode` should be `ReadWrite`